# Make my .mdx <pre> fit the html and body and be responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I have a gatsby blog based on .mdx files, I styled my `<pre>` in CSS but at this moment the `<pre>` container I wrote down in my .mdx files won't fit the HTML and Body size of the screen, and it seems not responsive at all.

My blog-post template:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"

import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { BiTime } from 'react-icons/bi'
import { MdComputer } from 'react-icons/md'
import { CgPacman } from 'react-icons/cg'

import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Alert from '../components/alerts'
import Feedback from '../components/Feedback'
import Share from '../components/Share'

export default function Template({ data }){
    const post = data.mdx
    const share = data.site

    return(
        <Layout>
            <div className="blog-cont">
                <h2>{post.frontmatter.title}</h2>

                <div className="legend">
                    <ul>
                        <li><MdComputer /> OS: {post.frontmatter.os}</li>
                        <li><BiTime /> Time: {post.frontmatter.time}</li>
                        <li><CgPacman/> Difficulty: {post.frontmatter.diff}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <h6>Posted by {post.frontmatter.author} on {post.frontmatter.date}</h6>
                <Alert alert={post.frontmatter.color}>
                    <h2>WARNING!</h2>
                    <p>{post.frontmatter.alert_cont}</p>
                </Alert>
                
                <MDXRenderer>{post.body}</MDXRenderer>

                <div className="underpost-cont">
                    <Feedback />
                    <Share socialConfig={{
                        twitterHandle: `${share.siteMetadata.twitterHandle}`,
                        config: {
                            url: `${share.siteMetadata.url}${post.frontmatter.path}`,
                            title: `${post.frontmatter.title}`
                        },
                    }} tags={post.frontmatter.tags}/>
                </div>

                <Button className="main-button"><Link to="/guides">Back to Guides</Link></Button>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
};

export const postQuery = graphql`
    query BlogPostByPath($path: String!){
        site {
            siteMetadata{
                url
                twitterHandle
            }
        }

        mdx(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path} }){
            body
            frontmatter{
                path
                title
                author
                date(formatString: "DD MMM YYYY")
                color
                alert_cont
                os
                time
                diff
                tags
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

My CSS:

```js
pre {
  background: #262626;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

The .mdx code:

````js
```
powershell "(Get-WmiObject -query ‘select * from SoftwareLicensingService’).OA3xOriginalProductKey"
```
````

And this is the result:

[image]

The `<pre>` is not responsive at all as the rest of my .mdx text.

Anyone could help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to React, Gatsby or MDX, it's just how the `<pre>` tag works (specifically, it preserves whitespace). If you'd like to make it responsive, set the `max-width` and `overflow-x` properties on it.

```css
pre {
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  padding: 1em;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<pre>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit habitant, leo tellus ligula eu curae platea vivamus et cubilia, fringilla phasellus laoreet sociosqu facilisis a luctus.
Pulvinar leo vitae etiam aptent diam sem adipiscing viverra consectetur purus magna, ullamcorper praesent litora accumsan sociosqu elit facilisi blandit volutpat dictum mollis nisl, magnis cursus nisi eros habitasse eleifend mus ultricies neque rutrum.
</pre>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists even if I add max-width and overflow rules to my CSS. At a certain point, it seems like the text stops the resizing of the container and it goes out of the HTML and body container. This makes my page zoomed or smaller in mobile mode.

Comment: @emaprov Again, MDX does not have anything to do with how a browser renders your `<pre>` tag; if you're having CSS problems, it would be best to to share the HTML markup being produced along with the CSS you're attempting to use to style it.

Comment: The HTML produced is simple: `<pre><code>"lorem ipsum"</code></pre>` inside my `<div className="blog-containre">`. But it isn't still responsive at all, it looks like the `word-wrap: break-word;` doesn't break the break the word related to the pre containter

Comment: That's correct, because the `<pre>` tag preserves whitespace. If you want your words to wrap, don't use `<pre>`. You can still make the element responsive as I've demonstrated above (having it adapt to the size of the parent and allow scrolling within to access the contents).